# Remove one event from eventlog (or cast EventRecord to EventLogEntry)

Tags: c#, .net, events, system.diagnostics, event-viewer

My code sifts through events from a remote PC to test whether there are some `6008 (unexpected reboot)` events.

I'm using code like:

```
EventLog log = new EventLog("System",remoteMachine);
EventLogEntryCollection entries = log.Entries;
var entries_filtered = entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().Where (x => x.EventID=6008);
foreach (EventLogEntry entry in entries) {//my logic here}
```

During the process, I don't like the way that every event is logged ('reading event'), and so I've come up with two solutions:

1. Find a way to delete events with some features, so I can delete my
   reading events
2. Before reading, copy the evtx file and read event from this file.

But in this case, I need to use something like:

```
EventLogReader elr = new EventLogReader("C:\\myevents.evtx");    
EventRecord a = elr.ReadEvent();
```

I need to find a way to cast the `EventRecord` to a `EventLogEntry` or the `EventReader` to a `EventLogEntryCollection` to remove the need to change the entire logic beneath.

Any ideas for the two cases?

Thanks